# Get multiple images array inside array of content

Tags: php, arrays, json, loops, foreach

what I'm trying to achieve is to get all available images from userphotos posted with the same photo_title/timestamp into an array and the amount of images posted into the designated post under streamitem_id.

Currently the post inserts as it should but if I upload multiple images at one time, only one shows in the post. how would I go about making `$posts['streamitem_imageuploaded']`an array inside the already constructed array 'posts'.

Here is what I have so far.

```
$call = "SELECT *
FROM streamdata m
JOIN user t1 ON m.streamitem_creator = t1.id
JOIN user t2 ON m.streamitem_target = t2.id
WHERE 
m.streamitem_id > ".$_GET['streamitem_id']." 
ORDER BY m.streamitem_timestamp DESC";
$check1 = mysqli_query($mysqli, $call) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));

$json = array(
    'posts' => array(),
);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($check1)){

$posts = array();


         $posts['streamitem_id'] = $row['streamitem_id'];


        //start of image code. only ouputs one image in each 'posts' array. 
$sqlhhh = "SELECT * FROM userphotos WHERE photo_name='".$row['photo_title']."' AND photo_ownerid='".$row['streamitem_creator']."' AND photo_datetime='".$row['streamitem_timestamp']."' ORDER BY photo_id DESC";
$resulthhh = mysqli_query ($mysqli,$sqlhhh)or die(mysqli_error($mysqli)); 
$photo_num=mysqli_num_rows($resulthhh);

$images = array();
while ($rowhhh = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resulthhh)) {
$rowhhh = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resulthhh);
    $images[] = $rowhhh['photo_imagedata'];
}

foreach ($images as  $ima){

    if($photo_num==1){
        $posts['streamitem_imageuploaded']='<img  src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'. base64_encode($ima) .'" />';
    }else{
        $posts['streamitem_imageuploaded']='<img class="stream_images" style="width:235px;height:200px;object-fit:cover;margin:2px;padding:2px;" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'. base64_encode($ima) .'" />';
    }

}


$json['posts'][] =  $posts;
}
}
echo json_encode($json);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, you're overwriting `$posts['streamitem_imageuploaded']` in each iteration of `foreach` loop, and that's why you're always getting the last image in `$posts['streamitem_imageuploaded']`. You've to append those `<img ... />`(s) to `$posts['streamitem_imageuploaded']` in each iteration.

So change your `foreach` loop in the following way,

```
foreach ($images as  $ima){
    if($photo_num==1){
        $posts['streamitem_imageuploaded'] = '<img  src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'. base64_encode($ima) .'" />';
    }else{
        $posts['streamitem_imageuploaded'][] = '<img class="stream_images" style="width:235px;height:200px;object-fit:cover;margin:2px;padding:2px;" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'. base64_encode($ima) .'" />';
    }
}
```

Comment: It still seems to be the same with this edit. Only showing one image when I posted two.

Comment: @Gateway Check your database table first, make sure it has all the images' information. Then do `var_dump($images);` in your code and check if this array has all the desired images' information or not.

Comment: it gets the first image also, not the last.

Comment: Okay I think i know what the issue is. it has turned into an array now. Only because the images are in two separate posts under photo_streamitem_id under userphotos. I need to merge them somehow with a query so they come out under the same id.